# GWT center DialogBox on zoom

Tags: java, gwt, zooming, dialog

i am developing a `GWT` `mobile` application with `GWT 2.4`. i want my `DialogBox` to be seen always on the center of the user's `viewport` on zoom or on normal view. On normal view, `center()` can handle it but when the page is zoom, the `DialogBox` pops on center of the whole browser window which includes the scroll part of the page not on the center of the user's viewport. how to do this? please help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach a handler to your window that catches the zoom event. In this handler, you call

```
myDialogBox.setPopupPosition((Window.getClientWidth() - myDialogBox.getOffsetWidth())/2, (Window.getClientHeight() - myDialogBox.getOffsetHeight())/2);
}
```

You may need to add a check for situations when your dialog is bigger than the browser window, if you want to treat them differently.

Answer (score 0):

i have to `implements ResizeHandler` on my window and on its constructor, i have added `ResizeEvent` handler > `Window.addResizeHandler(this);`. since i'm implementing the `ResizeHandler` interface, i need to override the following:

```
@Override
public void onResize(ResizeEvent event) {
    if (isShowing() ) { //check if popup is showing
        int left = (Window.getClientWidth() * 0.5 - (widthOfMyWindow * 0.5) );
        int top = (Window.getClientHeight() * 0.5  - (heightOfMyWindow * 0.5) );

        setPopupPosition( left < 10 ? 10 : left, top < 0 ? 0 : top );
    }
}
```